# PayPal Onboard sellers before payment

Tags: paypal

I am trying to create an application that enables sellers to create a PayPal account which then my platform will use their PayPal details to payout them whenever a pucharse is made via the application. I checked the documentation for creating a seller onboarding sign-up link but I couldn't able to figure out how to use this in the NodeJS environment.

```
curl -v -X POST https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/customer/partner-referrals \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>" \
  -d '{
    "tracking_id": "<Tracking-ID>",
    "operations": [
      {
        "operation": "API_INTEGRATION",
        "api_integration_preference": {
          "rest_api_integration": {
            "integration_method": "PAYPAL",
            "integration_type": "THIRD_PARTY",
            "third_party_details": {
              "features": [
                "PAYMENT",
                "REFUND"
             ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "products": [
      "EXPRESS_CHECKOUT"
    ],
    "legal_consents": [
      {
        "type": "SHARE_DATA_CONSENT",
        "granted": true
      }
    ]
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no SDK for such APIs, but you could use the code (for other APIs) in [Checkout-NodeJS-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NodeJS-SDK) as a starting point and use it to create your own HTTPS calls for this API you want to integrate, based on that curl sample.

Alternatively, use one of the many [HTTPS request libraries](https://openbase.com/categories/js/best-nodejs-http-request-libraries) available for NodeJS, such as axios or got, to implement the request of that curl sample.  You will need to implement an Oauth2 request first to get an Access Token with the clientid/secret.

Comment: It appears to be a little complicated, but thank you. I could try your first suggestion but then I will still need to figure out how to acquire the access tokens.

Comment: The Checkout-NodeJS-SDK has code for obtaining an access token.